# When does the plural have to be used for words for numbers like "millions"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, syntax, numerals

For example, I understand in English I have to say 100 million persons. But the word "millions" also exist. In Spanish I would have to use the plural for million in the first sentence. Then when the plural for words for numbers like "millions" has to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words for counting numbers are usually singular in form because the plural marker goes at the end of the noun phrase:

> two hundred bottle**s**
>
> ninety nine red balloon**s**
>
> one hundred and one dalmation**s**
>
> a hundred dollar**s**
>
> = one hundred dollar**s**
>
> three hundred dollar**s**
>
> four score and seven year**s** ago

You often hear the plural words for these quantity numbers (tens, hundreds, thousands, and so on) in expressions of inexact quantities:

> Hundred**s** of books.
>
> This painting is worth million**s**.
>
> Ten**s** of flies were in the room.
>
> There are hundred**s** of ways to do that.
>
> Score**s** of children.

Answer (score 0):

**Five million** people. [five million is considered an adjective].

**Millions of people** use the program every day. [millions is a noun.]

Both in Spanish are **milliones** with es, the plural form for both these cases.